# License of program that is using Qt

Tags: qt, licensing

Licensing questions are hard to me. Please tell me what license must have the program that use open-source version of Qt? Must it be LGPLv2.1 or any GPL i want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it can be closed license if you want, as long you don't don't distribute QT under a closed license.

Answer (score 1):

Qt comes in two flavors:

- [LGPL'ed](http://qt.nokia.com/products/licensing/)
- [Commercial](http://qt.digia.com/)

Both licences you mentioned are good to use (incl. both static and dynamic linking).

With LGPL'ed Qt you can go with proprietary licence as well, but in this case your software should be restricted to use dynamic linking only.